# Get Skype for Business Contact Status with powershell

Tags: powershell, skype, skype-for-business

is it possible to get the Skype status of a contact in powershell?
If so, how?
any Ideas? I didnt find much, only this question:
[Get Skype for Business User Status/Availability issue in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104066/get-skype-for-business-user-status-availability-issue-in-powershell)

But I dont have the file this guy imports. I only have lync.exe or Microsoft.Lync.Model, but not.dll and its also in a zip.

Answer (score 0):

The library is part of the Lync SDK. Check [Use PowerShell to integrate with the Lync 2013 SDK for Skype for Business – Part 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-integrate-with-the-lync-2013-sdk-for-skype-for-business-part-1/) for more detals.